# Explicitly determining which pure function to use

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

One of the examples from [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors) is:

`pure (+) <*> Just 3 <*> Just 5`

He states:

> *So at first, we have `pure (+)`, which is `Just (+)`*

I'm assuming that Haskell is using type inference on the `<*>` function to determine that the `pure` function on the LHS will be the one from the `Maybe` instance of the `Applicative` type class (based on the fact we're using `Just 5` on the RHS, and `Just` is a `Maybe`).

However, is there ever a case where you have a value you'd like to turn into an Applicative Functor using the `pure` method, but you aren't going to use it right away via the `<*>` function and thus Haskell can't determine which `pure` function to use?  If so, **how would you be explicit state which `pure` function to use**?

Or, is it the case that Haskell won't try to  determine which `pure` function until the result of the `pure` function is used in some context (such as when you feed it to a `<*>` function at some point)

Comment: This is a type inference question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would give it a type annotation. If you were defining it as a variable, you would use a top-level type signature:

```
foo :: Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
foo = pure (+)
```

(This also works in `let` and `where` clauses.)

Or if you were using it in an expression, you'd write `(pure (+) :: Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer))`.

You can also get the relevant `pure` function without having to apply it to an argument. Since we have:

```
pure :: (Applicative f) => a -> f a
```

...we can say `(pure :: a -> Maybe a)` to get a `pure` of the desired type. But `(pure :: a -> Maybe a) (+)` is more confusing than `pure (+) :: Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`, so the latter is probably more useful in general.

The last sentence of your question is correct, however: you can assign `pure (+)` to a variable without a type signature, and use it later at a specific concrete type (such as `Maybe (Integer -> Integer -> Integer)`) without having to use any type annotations at all. (There's a slight restriction: if you define it as a top-level variable without any type signature, then you can only use it as *one* specific type, not two in different places, due to the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)... but you probably don't need to worry about that.)

Comment: The final paragraph of the question text is also true: Often, if you can't decide on a concrete applicative functor to use yet, you also do not have to. There is no need to immediately pick a concrete type, you can define derived code that's overloaded in the applicative functor.